# INTERNAL: IO error: /var/shuffle/sorted-dataset-4/1011: No space left on device when talking to tcp://localhost:12345

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to process 2.5TB of data from BigQuery. Code for beginning of pipeline:

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
    p.apply(BigQueryIO.Read.fromQuery(
            "select * from table_query(Events, 'table_id contains \"20150601\"') where id is not null"))
            .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<TableRow, KV<String, TableRow>>() {
                @Override
                public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
                    c.output(KV.of((String) c.element().get("id"), c.element()));
                }
            })).apply(GroupByKey.<String, TableRow>create())
```

For DataflowPipelineOptions I set only staging location to folder on GCS and project.

Job was successfully started on GCP an run for a while. Final job status is failed due to internal io errors.

```
Jul 16, 2015, 8:45:47 PM(297a156f6f2a50b2): java.lang.RuntimeException:java.io.IOException: INTERNAL: IO error: /var/shuffle/sorted-dataset-4/1011: No space left on device when talking to tcp://localhost:12345
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase$1.output(ParDoFnBase.java:154)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase$1.output(ParDoFnBase.java:117)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunner.java:314)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunner.java:475)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.ReifyTimestampAndWindowsDoFn.processElement(ReifyTimestampAndWindowsDoFn.java:40)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: INTERNAL: IO error: /var/shuffle/sorted-dataset-4/1011: No space left on device when talking to tcp://localhost:12345
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ApplianceShuffleWriter.write(Native Method)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ChunkingShuffleEntryWriter.writeChunk(ChunkingShuffleEntryWriter.java:72)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ChunkingShuffleEntryWriter.put(ChunkingShuffleEntryWriter.java:56)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ShuffleSink$ShuffleSinkWriter.add(ShuffleSink.java:258)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ShuffleSink$ShuffleSinkWriter.add(ShuffleSink.java:169)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.WriteOperation.process(WriteOperation.java:90)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:147)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase$1.output(ParDoFnBase.java:152)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase$1.output(ParDoFnBase.java:117)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunner.java:314)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunner.java:475)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.ReifyTimestampAndWindowsDoFn.processElement(ReifyTimestampAndWindowsDoFn.java:40)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(DoFnRunner.java:167)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.processElement(DoFnRunner.java:152)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase.processElement(ParDoFnBase.java:188)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:52)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:147)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase$1.output(ParDoFnBase.java:152)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase$1.output(ParDoFnBase.java:117)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunner.java:314)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunner.java:475)
at com.outfit7.dataflow.ante.Example$5.processElement(Example.java:41)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(DoFnRunner.java:167)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.processElement(DoFnRunner.java:152)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase.processElement(ParDoFnBase.java:188)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:52)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:147)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:171)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:117)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:66)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.executeWork(DataflowWorker.java:220)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:167)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:134)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:146)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:131)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there any way to be sure that job will finish successfully? How should I set num of workers and diskSizeGb or to make estimation on size used on one worker? Is GroupByKey executed on one worker or is shared/sharded? As I understand GroupByKey "waits" to process all data before pass PCollection to next element in pipeline.

Comment: Hi Jure, I'm looking into this and will get back to you later today.

Comment: We're working on an FAQ entry about this topic, stay tuned.

Comment: Before the larger entry is ready to go, I'd suggest running with --numWorkers=30, which should be sufficient to complete the pipeline with the default disk size of 250GB.

Comment: Tnx for the hint. I'll try. Can you please explain what is the reasoning behind? Or should I wait for FAQ entry?

Comment: Just the default disk size with some headroom -- more detail to come.

Comment: @JureGrom Did your job succeed that time? I just faced a similar issue and my job is still running.

Answer (score 1):

From https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/faq#question-45:

> This error indicates that your local disk has insufficient space to process this job. If you are running your job with default settings, your job is running on 3 workers, each with 250 GB of local disk space, and with no auto-scaling. Consider [modifying the default settings](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params) to increase the number of workers available to your job, to increase the default disk size per worker, or to enable auto-scaling.